# How to connect SharePoint 2013 and Visual Studio 2012 to create a simple form?

Tags: 2013, development, form, visual-studio-2012

I am a beginner when it comes to SharePoint so please bear with me, I apologize in advance for my inaccuracies.

Here is what I need to do... I need to build a form in C# .NET in VS 2012, deploy it to a SharePoint 2013 site, the users be able to create a new form, and the form entries appear in a list.  I tried looking on line for a tutorial on how to go about doing this but I am lost in the sheer amount of information regarding SP.

I am able to build the form in VS, so I am not asking for code.  Rather, I am looking for how to set it up so that I can easily deploy and work the form through SP.  I have a farm already set up and the servers are in place.  We have done this before for another project so I know that VS and SP are configured correctly.

Is there a sequence I need to follow (as in in build the list in SP first then use the fields in VS, or create a site collection in SP, build the list in VS, and just hook them up, etc...?).  I created a new SP 2013 project in VS 2012, but do I create a new web part now?

I know this is a large question, but like I said I did do research but the amount of info regarding SP is overwhelming.  I am just a lowly developer trying to build a form and connect it to SP.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

1. In Visual Studio, create a visual Web part and apply your code logic.
2. Set your web application path in properties of visual web part
3. Right click on visual web part and choose deploy.
4. Go to your web application, edit the page
5. In insert section ,choose insert web part.
6. From the menu, you select custom web part. your web part will appear.select it and than add it.
7. Save.